# How can I have a iPhone (connected via lightning cable) play back it's sound on a Macbook?

Tags: iphone, audio, headphones, midi

I have iShowU audio capture (2 ins, 2 outs), and my iPhone (2 ins) in a Aggregate device, and a Multi-Output device with iShowU Audio Capture and my Headphones. When I play audio from my phone and my mic on my mac is set to the aggregate device, and output is Multi-Output.

My mic clearly picks up my phone's audio but I can't hear it via my mac's headphone jack. How can I set it in a way so that my phone plays audio I can hear on my mac?

I'm playing video from Safari, Photos, Chrome. Not iTunes / Apple Music.